# Popup with dialog not showing up properly

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have the following popup with a dialog inside:

```
<af:popup childCreation="immediate" id="p1" autoCancel="enabled" clientComponent="true">
                        <af:dialog id="d1" type="yesNo"
                                   dialogListener="#{patientModalityValidator.mydialog_listener}"
                                   cancelTextAndAccessKey="Cancel" title="Alert" closeIconVisible="false"
                                   shortDesc="ShortDesc" clientComponent="true"">
                            <af:outputText value="Are you sure?" id="myid"
                                           clientComponent="true"/>
                        </af:dialog>
                    </af:popup>
```

This popup gets invoked using the following code:

```
RichPopup popup= (RichPopup)JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot("p1");
popup.show(new RichPopup.PopupHints());
```

The problem is the popup shows up very small (like 5px wide and 5px high) and when I go into the browsers developer console I don't see any dialog content inside. If I set autoCancel to disabled it works fine, but I need autoCancel to handle if a user closes the popup before answering the dialog. I am using jdev11.1.2.4

UPDATE: It is a layout issue. This is what the html of the popup looks like:

```
<div style="top:auto;right:auto;left:auto;bottom:auto;width:auto;height:auto;position:relative;" id="r1:0:pt:p1::content">
    <div id="r1:0:pt:d1" title="ShortDesc" class="af_dialog">
        <div class="af_dialog_inactive-background" _afrpanelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="af_dialog_inactive-background" _afrpanelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="af_dialog_inactive-background" _afrpanelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="af_dialog_inactive-background" _afrpanelwindowbackground="1" style="display: none;"></div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" class="af_dialog_main">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_header-start" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_hse">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_header" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_hce">
                        <table style="cursor:default" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" summary="">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="r1:0:pt:d1::_ticn" class="af_dialog_icon-region" style="display:none"></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="af_dialog_header-content-center" id="r1:0:pt:d1::tb" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
                                        <div id="r1:0:pt:d1::_ttxt" class="af_dialog_title">Alert</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_header-end" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_hee">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_content-start" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_cse">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_content" id="r1:0:pt:d1::contentContainer">
                        <div id="r1:0:pt:d1::_ccntr" class="af_dialog_content-center" style="width:250px;height:250px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;"><span id="r1:0:pt:pgl1" class="af_panelGroupLayout" style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px"><span id="r1:0:pt:myid">Are you sure?</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_content-end" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_cee">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_footer-start" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_fse">
                        <div></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_footer" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_fce">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" summary="">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_footer-content" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_fcc">
                                        <button id="r1:0:pt:d1::yes" class="af_dialog_footer-button p_AFTextOnly" onclick="return false;" _afrpdo="yes">Yes</button>
                                        <button id="r1:0:pt:d1::no" class="af_dialog_footer-button p_AFTextOnly" onclick="return false;" _afrpdo="no">No</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="bottom">
                                        <div class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_resize-icon-region">
                                            <a tabindex="-1" class="af_dialog_resize-icon-style" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_ree" title="Resize"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="p_AFResizable af_dialog_footer-end" id="r1:0:pt:d1::_fee">
                        <div></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "Are you sure" text and the yes/no buttons are there, but the text is not showing although it is in the source code.

Comment: tried changing childCreation to deferred? 
Plus you can set height and width to the popup by setting contentWidth and contentHeight in af:dialog

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work. I dont think it has anything to do with the layout because in the browser's developer console the dialog content isn't even showing up on the page source HTML.

Comment: @Sam Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `stretchChildren="first"` attribute to your dialog

Comment: Hmm... I have seen such kind of behavior in my project some days before. I used imagelink inside filter facet of the table, and this link triggered popup appereance. Inside this popup was a table, but at runtime i saw only 5x5px area

Comment: popup.show is inside a bean. When a button gets clicked a method inside of a bean call  input.show(new RichPopup.PopupHints());

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your `af:outputText` inside a `af:panelGrouplayout` and add styleclass on top of the panelgrouplayout. Even you can add inlineStyle also like the below

```
 <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical"
                         inlineStyle="margin-top:5px">

     <af:outputText value="Are you sure?" id="myid"
                    clientComponent="true"/>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Thanks..

Comment: Does not do anything. My updated question has the html which is being produced by the popup

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a 'contentWidth' property in the af:dialog.
eg :

```
<af:popup id="submitPopUp">
    <af:dialog id="d1" type="ok"
               title="popup"
               contentWidth="400">
      <af:outputText value="text"
                     id="ot3"/>
    </af:dialog>
  </af:popup>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't help. My updated question has the html which is being produced by the popup

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the root cause of your issue as you said the popup appeared really small. (the text is there but the pop up doesnt have enough width to show it) Could you try removing the other properties ? (dialogListener and clientComponent)

Answer (score 0):

Try this output label to add text

```
<af:popup binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.p1}"
                                  id="p1">
    <af:dialog binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.d2}"
             id="d2" title="DECISION" contentWidth="250"
             contentHeight="100" type="none">
        <af:panelGroupLayout binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.pgl15}"
                             id="pgl15" layout="horizontal"
                             halign="center">
            <af:outputLabel value="Do you want to Amend this LG"
                              binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.ol1}"
                              id="ol1"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
        <af:panelGroupLayout binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.pgl20}"
                             id="pgl20" layout="horizontal"
                             halign="center">
            <af:image binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.i1}"
                        id="i1" source="/download.jpg"/>
            <af:spacer width="10" height="10"
                     binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.s5}"
                     id="s5"/>
            <af:commandButton text="NO"
                            binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.cb4}"
                            id="cb4"/>
            <af:spacer width="10" height="10"
                     binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.s3}"
                     id="s3"/>
            <af:commandButton text="YES"
                            action="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.newactionamend}"
                            binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_NewBankGurantee.cb5}"
                            id="cb5"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
    </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```